# find + sed not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sed, find

I am trying to run a script that searches certain folders for certain files and, if found, replaces an entire line with another sentence. What I tried is below:

```
#! /bin/sh

I=$(find /home -maxdepth 7 -iname desktop-items-0.conf -exec sed '6s/.*/teste/' {} \;)
echo "$I"
```

Comment: whats the output? that may help us a GREAT deal.

Comment: BashFAQ #21, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021, may be of interest.

Comment: Providing contents of your `desktop-items-0.conf` (at least the 6th line), and the actual result, would be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
#! /bin/sh
I=$(find /home -maxdepth 7 -iname desktop-items-0.conf -exec sed '6s/^.*$/teste/' {} \;)
echo "$I"
```

ex:

desktop-items-0.conf

```
    [*]
    wallpaper_mode=center
    wallpaper_common=1
    wallpaper=/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork/raspberry-pi-logo-small.png
    desktop_bg=#d6d6d3d3dede
    desktop_fg=#000000
    desktop_shadow=#d6d6d3d3dede
    desktop_font=Roboto Light 12
    show_wm_menu=0
    sort=mtime;ascending;
    show_documents=0
    show_trash=1
    show_mounts=0
```

after run

line 6 change as below;

```
[*]
wallpaper_mode=center
wallpaper_common=1
wallpaper=/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork/raspberry-pi-logo-small.png
desktop_bg=#d6d6d3d3dede
teste
desktop_shadow=#d6d6d3d3dede
desktop_font=Roboto Light 12
show_wm_menu=0
sort=mtime;ascending;
show_documents=0
show_trash=1
show_mounts=0
```

If you want to modify file. use sed -i